# How and where do I set up a FK for a 1 to many relationship using EF Core 6

Tags: .net-core, upgrade, ef-core-6.0

I have 3 tables, `Customer`, `Program` and `ProgramRegistrations`.  Customer is an IdentityUser and in the DB AspNetUsers.  My model for Customer has a `List<ProgramRegistration>`.  ProgramRegistrations is a table with 2 columns, CustomerId and ProgramId, which make a composite PK for that table.

When I try to save a new `ProgramRegistration`, I get the following error:
`The value of 'ProgramRegistrationEntity.CustomerId' is unknown when attempting to save changes. This is because the property is also part of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is not known.`

In the ProgramRegistrationConfiguration file we make the key,
`builder.HasKey(x => new {x.CustomerId, x.ProgramId});`

In the CustomerConfiguration file I have
`builder.HasMany(x => x.ProgramRegistrations).WithOne(y => y.Customer).HasForeignKey(x => x.CustomerId);`

We're in the process of migrating from EF Core 3 to EF Core 6 and this is a sticking point for us.  I don't understand what the error message is trying to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, Your code should look like the following

```
// Customer entity
public class Customer : IdentityUser
{
   // Other properties of Customer
    public List<ProgramRegistration> ProgramRegistrations { get; set; }
}

// Program entity
public class Program
{
   public int ProgramId { get; set; }
   // Other properties of Program
}

// ProgramRegistration entity
public class ProgramRegistration
{
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
   public int ProgramId { get; set; }
   // Other properties of ProgramRegistration

   public Customer Customer { get; set; }
   public Program Program { get; set; }
```

}

```
  // CustomerConfiguration
  public class CustomerConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
  {
     public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
    {
       builder.HasMany(customer => customer.ProgramRegistrations)
           .WithOne(programRegistration => programRegistration.Customer)
           .HasForeignKey(programRegistration => 
           programRegistration.CustomerId);
    }
}

// ProgramRegistrationConfiguration
public class ProgramRegistrationConfiguration : 
 IEntityTypeConfiguration<ProgramRegistration>
{
   public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ProgramRegistration> builder)
   {
       builder.HasKey(programRegistration => new { 
        programRegistration.CustomerId, programRegistration.ProgramId });
   }
}
```

And register above config to your db context onmodelcreating event

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   // Register configurations
   modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CustomerConfiguration());
   modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new 
      ProgramRegistrationConfiguration());
    // Other configurations
}
```